# Windows Server 2008 R2 allows many local RDS connections, but only one remote

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

I'm trying to set up an instance of Server 2008R2 with RDS. I have a 20 User and 20 Device CAL that I can choose from, but either one is not enabling me to have multiple remote connections. I can connect via localhost as much as I want, but remotely, I only get one. I have the firewall temporarily disabled, I have the network adapter configured in RDS to allow unlimited connections, and the policy for multiple sign-ons of the same user is allowed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're question doesn't make sense. The `unlimited` option is only available if you have the RDS role installed. Also, what do you mean you can connect via localhost as mush as you want? How are you connecting via localhost? Can you post a screenshot of the Roles you have installed and of the RDP protocol settings showing your unlimited option?

Comment: I have the RDS role installed. If I use Remote Desktop Connection, I can connect locally via localhost as much as I want, for as many sessions as I want. Trying to do this remotely does not work. I will post a screenshot shortly.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by connecting to localhost. Do you mean that you are using RDP to connect to the server from itself?

Comment: Yes. I am able to do so with user (non-admin) credentials, for multiple sessions, but if I try to RDP from outside the server itself, it only allows one connection.

Comment: outside of the server, as in from a computer on the same LAN, or is this a hosted server and you are trying to RDP into it from outside of its LAN?

Comment: The server is in the same LAN. I can successfully make a single RDP connection from my workstation to the server, but cannot make another connection afterwards. Within the server, however, I can continue to create sessions.

Comment: @joeqwerty: the screenshots you wanted are added.

Comment: @d_r_w What does your event viewer has to say?

Comment: It mentioned a need to add NetworkService to the Terminal Server License group. I did that, rebooted, still no dice.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you try to log in with the *same user* all the time. Even on RDS, this is by default restricted.

I assume you can logon with a different user.

If you want to use the same user, use this procedure:
http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000471.htm

> 1. On the server, click Start and in the search/run box type tsconfig.msc{enter}. Locate "Restrict each user to a single session"
>      Right click > Properties.
> 2. Remove the tick from "Restrict each user to a single session" > Apply > OK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup and configure terminal services for multiple remote desktop connections. By default, you only get 2.

Check this link to read up on what you want to do.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770759.aspx

Comment: The Remote Desktop Session Host role is definitely installed and configured, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in licensing. Have you set up TS Licensing services? Have you configured RDS to use this licensing server? It licence type correct?